# Prove the completion of the span of $ \left\{ e^{i\lambda t} \right\} _{\lambda\in \mathbb R}$ is not separable

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, inner-products, orthogonality, fourier-transform

Let $G$ be the span of $ \left\{ e^{i\lambda t} \right\} _{\lambda\in \mathbb R}$ with inner product $$ \left\langle f,g \right\rangle =\lim _{T\rightarrow \infty}\frac 1{2T}\int_{-T}^Tf\bar g .$$
I need to show the completion of $G$ is not separable.  I'm guessing the proof should go by contradiction but I have no clue what to do... Help!

Comment: The completion with respect to what norm?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich $L^2$-norm

Comment: ??? _What_ $L^2$ norm? If you're talking about the $L^2$ norm on $[0,2\pi]$ then the completion _is_ separable. If you're talking about $L^2(\Bbb R)$ this makes no sense because those functions are not in $L^2$ in the first place.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich sorry I took a while. I missed crucial details and asked a "wrong question".

Comment: Ok. Actually that's what I assumed the problem was, but I have this thing about how the OP should at least be able to get the question straight. With that inner product the $e_\lambda$ are orthonormal. Hence $||e_\lambda-e_{\lambda'}||=\sqrt 2$ if $\lambda\ne\lambda'$. That makes it clear the space is not separable, right?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Sorry, why does that equality imply non-separability?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich think I got it: suppose separable. Then each ball of radius $<\sqrt 2$ about each basis element should contain at least one element of the countable dense set, which is impossible since there are countably many basis elements. I still don't see why ask about the completion of $G$ instead of $G$ itself..

Comment: Right. Yes, it's also true that the same argument shows that $G$ is not separable. Presumably the reason the question is about the completion is that the point was to give a "natural" example of a non-separable _Hilbert space_.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich "but I have this thing about how the OP should at least be able to get the question straight" Couldn't agree more. The inability of the majority of OPs on MSE to pose questions in a semi-coherent manner is eye opening - and alarming.

Comment: @zhw. Eye-opening and alarming. Also irritating when you're trying to get a correct statement out of the OP but that's too much trouble, they just go away. From which point of view our friend linalg is an exemplary human being...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $e_\lambda(t)=e^{i\lambda t}$. One can easily calculate the relevant integrals explicitly, showing that $\{e_\lambda:\lambda\in\Bbb R\}$ is an orthonormal subset of $G$. Hence the completion $H$ of $G$ is a non-separable Hilbert space, since $\{B(e_\lambda,\sqrt 2/2)\}$ is an uncountable collection of pairwise disjoint nonempty open sets.

---

**Comment** What's above was worked out in the comments; I'm posting this just because Questions are better with Answers. For the sake of adding something not in the comments:

In fact $H$ is, in a canonical way, $L^2$ of the *Bohr compactification* of $\Bbb R$. The Bohr compactification of a locally compact abelian group $A$ is defined like so: Let $\hat A$ be the dual group of $A$, and now let $\hat A'$ be the dual group, but with the discrete topology. The Bohr compactification of $A$ is the dual group of $\hat A'$.

(Saying that is a little silly, since it will not be new to most of the readers familiar with the context. Anyone who doesn't follow what I'm going on about in the previous paragraph but finds it interesting might check out, say, Rudin *Fourier Analysis on Groups*. Or you could start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin_duality#Bohr_compactification_and_almost-periodicity).)