# What is the Bohr compactification of a topological group and in particular of the real line? How can you define it?

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups, compactification

I have encountered the Bohr compactification in the context of Loop Quantum Cosmology and Polymer Quantum Mechanics and I cannot succeed understanding it in a straightforward way.
I just got my Master's Degree in Physics and at the moment I do not have an adequate background in topology that can help me to grasp these notions.
Is there a rigorous and understandable way to define the Bohr compactification in general and in particular the Bohr compactification of the real line?
Thank you all.

Comment: the real line case is mentioned here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1855027